# Sending Keystroke to another application using WinAPI

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, sendmessage, postmessage

I have to control another application by sending keystrokes to it like <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

I've tried a lot of things, but I can't get it working. So I'm trying to get this right on a simpler case.

This successfully sends `Hey` to the notepad:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var notepad, edit: HWND;
begin
  notepad := FindWindow('notepad', nil);
  edit := FindWindowEx(notepad, FindWindow('Edit', nil), nil, nil);

  SendMessage(edit, WM_CHAR, dword('H'), 0);
  SendMessage(edit, WM_CHAR, dword('e'), 0);
  SendMessage(edit, WM_CHAR, dword('y'), 0);
end;
```

And this successfully sends the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to the notepad, and also works with <kbd>F3</kbd> poping up the Find dialog.

```
notepad := FindWindow('notepad', nil);
PostMessage(notepad, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
PostMessage(notepad, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0);
```

But I don't know why using `SendMessage` doesn't work on the exemple above.

The best thing I could came up was something like this, which does nothing.

```
notepad := FindWindow('notepad', nil);
PostMessage(notepad, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
PostMessage(notepad, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan('F'), 0);
PostMessage(notepad, WM_KEYUP, VkKeyScan('F'), 0);
PostMessage(notepad, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 0);
```

I've found somewhere here a library which kinda emulate the VBScript send key functions, but just looking the code, it seems to just broadcast keys to the current application or all applications, since there's no Handle parameter.

Answer (score 7):

***Warning:** This method depends on implementation details, and should not be used if you need to guarantee the correctness of your program.* (On the other hand, you are already on that path. For instance, IIRC, in Windows 95 there isn't even a `Go to` dialog.)

I opened `notepad.exe` in my favourite Resource Editor, and investigated the menu bar. I noticed that the ID of the `Save` menu item is `3`. Hence, the following code executes the `Save` menu command in notepad:

```
var
  notepad: HWND;
begin
  notepad := FindWindow('notepad', nil);

  SendMessage(notepad, WM_COMMAND, 3, 0);
```

Similarly, `Find` is `21` in my version of `notepad.exe`. `Go to` is `24`.

**Update, according to comment:** If you need to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>, you can use `SendInput`:

```
var
  notepad: HWND;
  inputArray: array[0..3] of TInput;
begin
  notepad := FindWindow('notepad', nil);

  // TODO: Either exit if notepad isn't focused, or set focus to notepad

  FillChar(inputArray, length(inputArray) * sizeof(TInput), 0);

  inputArray[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inputArray[0].ki.wVk := VK_LCONTROL;
  inputArray[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inputArray[1].ki.wVk := VkKeyScan('S');
  inputArray[2].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inputArray[2].ki.wVk := VkKeyScan('S');
  inputArray[2].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  inputArray[3].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inputArray[3].ki.wVk := VK_LCONTROL;
  inputArray[3].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  SendInput(length(inputArray), inputArray[0], sizeof(TInput));
```

Comment: This is very  usefull but doesn't work for me, because I need to automate a task in a game which doesn't have standard windows components, so AFAIK I can't find any command ID, I can just send messages to the top window handle, and the only reliable way I can find is that the keystrokes are always the same.

Comment: Are there "old" versions of Delphi that do not support `absolute`? I thought that was inherited from Borland Pascal.

Comment: @AndriyM: My understanding is that it was introduced in Delphi 2009, but apparently David [disagrees](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15388716/revisions) on that one. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: I can see that you've already deleted the bit about `absolute`, so this is simply for confirmation. Delphi 6 and Delphi 2006, the two versions that I've been actively working with lately, support it, and I know for certain that that is the same `absolute` that I used quite often in Borland/Turbo Pascal. So yes, you can depend on it that all Delphi versions have `absolute`.

Comment: @AndriyM: Myself, I tried Delphi 4 on my Win95 machine. Even the syntax highlighter recognised `absolute`.

Comment: You don't need `absolute` at all here. The following syntax works fine in XE3: `SendInput(length(inputArray), inputarray[0], sizeof(TInput));`

Comment: Regarding absolute it has indeed existed since forever. It's a feature that the compiler engineers do not enjoy supporting and I expect it will disappear in the next gen compiler.

Comment: It worked, it's not ideally to `SetForegroundWindow(notepad)` but there's no better way yet. I have to ask what exactly the second parameter of sendInput, why it is inputarray[`0`] and not the whole array? I hope my question make sense

Comment: @Vitim_us: It actually is the whole array, sent by the address of the first element. The array is contiguous in memory (element `0` is directly followed by element `1`, etc.). The first value passed to the function is the number of elements in the array, and the second is the address of the first element. The third value is the size of each element in the array.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for SendInput? It is explained there.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using keybd_event for ages. It will always work even if everything else fails because it feeds the input directly into the interface between the keyboard driver and Windows. There's really no difference between typing manually and generating keys using the function below. Only disadvantage is that the target window must always remain in the foreground.

```
procedure SendKey(Wnd,VK : Cardinal; Ctrl,Alt,Shift : Boolean);
var
  MC,MA,MS : Boolean;
begin
  // Try to bring target window to foreground
  ShowWindow(Wnd,SW_SHOW);
  SetForegroundWindow(Wnd);

  // Get current state of modifier keys
  MC:=Hi(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL))>127;
  MA:=Hi(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU))>127;
  MS:=Hi(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))>127;

  // Press modifier keys if necessary (unless already pressed by real user)
  if Ctrl<>MC then keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,Byte(MC)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Alt<>MA then keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,Byte(MA)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Shift<>MS then keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0,Byte(MS)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

  // Press key
  keybd_event(VK,0,0,0);
  keybd_event(VK,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

  // Release modifier keys if necessary
  if Ctrl<>MC then keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,Byte(Ctrl)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Alt<>MA then keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,Byte(Alt)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Shift<>MS then keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0,Byte(Shift)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
end;
```

Comment: It can fail. It fails when another process inserts keyboard events which interleave. That is why SendInput exists. I don't know why you think keybd_event is better than SendInput.

Comment: Games might not always respond to SendMessage() so a lower-level function is required. I assumed SendInput is a higher-level function based on SendMessage(). I stand corrected.