# Finding the correct handle of Notepad++ to use in SendMessage()

Tags: winapi, lazarus, freepascal

I'm in my first try with *WinAPI* and I am trying to send some text from a *Delphi* program (well *Lazarus*) to Notepad++.

I already found a good example to use simple *Notepad*, that goes like this :

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Var1, Var2 : HWND;
Begin
    Var1 := FindWindow('notepad', nil);
    Var2 := FindWindowEx(Var1, FindWindow('Edit', nil), nil, nil);
    Clipboard.AsText:='This is some sample text.';
    SendMessage(Var2, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
End;
```

So this works fine for *Notepad*.
Now I would like to adapt it to use with any other program.
Taking *Notepad++* for example, how do I find it's equivalent to `'Edit'` used there in the `FindWindowEx()` ? Or let's say the correct cell and workbook to paste in *LibreOffice Calc*?

Any samples or clues?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use e.g. Spy++ for inspecting application windows. But there's no ultimate answer for every application. For example mentioned LibreOffice has its own API that you should use.

Comment: `notepad++` and `Scintilla` class names

Comment: "any other program", you basically need a database of every program ever written for Windows. Reconsider your objectives.

Comment: @Victoria Thanks for the tip. I guess that's exactly what i need. Will give it a try.

Comment: @RbMm, will test and let you know, thanks

Comment: @JonathanPotter, it will be for a very specific usage. I'm just testing with other programs for now to understand exactly how it works. Thanks.

Comment: I would not be happy if random programs overwrote my clipboard!

Comment: How are you planning to identify the correct instance, when multiple instances of the target application are running? And @Anders is correct here, too: The clipboard belongs to the user. Your app has no business trashing the user's data.

Comment: The clipboard belongs to the user,  not the programmer. I'd rethink what you're trying to do (or at least how you're doing it).

Comment: Don't worry guys, it's for an automated task on a specific situation, just avoiding user input (and typing errors). I'm sure he will not mind ;)

And the clipboard, again, is just for testing. Will have to use other method as i can't risk pasting whatever the user had just copy.

Basically, the app i'm developing will get info from a QR code, do some treatment and send it to some 3rd party app, filling the corresponding fields minimising user input. A nice little project.

Comment: The tool to use is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). That still doesn't help you answer the question: How do you identify the correct instance to automate, in case there are multiple instances of the target application running.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the info. In this particular case i know the target application won't allow more that one instance. Will not be a problem there.

Will take a closer look to UI Automation

Comment: You don't need the clipboard to set the text of an edit control.

Comment: In the provided code, the call to `FindWindowEx()` is wrong. It should be `FindWindowEx(Var1, 0, 'Edit', nil)` instead. The original code is using `FindWindow('Edit', nil)` to search for a top-window window and treat it as if it were a child window. It should be looking for an actual child window instead. The original code "works" only because `FindWindow('Edit', nil)` fails and returns 0, and then `FindWindowEx()` ends up returning the 1st child window, which *happens* to be the actual `Edit` window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks for the explanation.
Actualy, i started from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853732/sending-keystroke-to-another-application-using-winapi) and have been experimenting since there.
I corrected my code and now is working fine.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz
I'm planing not to do that but if you can point me to a better direction it'll help me get there faster. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulo you can send a WM_SETTEXT. message.

Comment: I'm closing this as for the question asked the solution was found between **RbMm** and **Remy Lebeau**.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks a lot.